# Is there a way to implement an incremental ID in DBT integrated with Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a scenario where I am fetching data from a source to a target. The target model  is materialised as incremental because the source table changes often with new records. The issue is, the source table does not have a unique ID and I want to be able to able to create a Unique ID in the target which should start with 1 and increment by 1 as data keeps appending into the target table

Source table

```
|name | CreatedAT
|lee  | 2020-04-04 15:05:15.400
|john | 2020-04-04 15:05:15.400
|kate | 2020-04-04 15:05:15.400
```

Expected Target Table

```
|ID   |name | CreatedAT
|1    |lee  | 2020-04-04 15:05:15.400
|2    |john | 2020-04-04 15:05:15.400
|3    |kate | 2020-04-04 15:05:15.400
```

Model for the target table

```
{{ config(materialized = 'incremental') }}

 WITH people AS(
    SELECT  Row_Number() Over (Order by CreatedAT AS ID,
             *
    FROM {{ source('leeek', 'property') }}
    {% if is_incremental() %}
     where  > (select max(CreatedAT) from {{this}}
    {% endif %}

   )
   select * from people
```

The model works for incremental load from the source to Target but im not sure how to assign incremental ID starting from 1.

The model above creates a ID starting with 1,2,3 but when new rows are created in the source and dbt runs, ID starts from 1,2,3 instead of 4,5,6

Comment: Hi - why not just add AUTOINCREMENT to the column definition?

Comment: dbt does not support autoincremental

Comment: @NickW mean to say, add the field in Snowflake table.

Comment: The idea is the build the table from dbt and not in snowflake

Comment: The combination of `name` + `CreatedAT` feels unique in your example. Is that the case?

Comment: Sometimes name and CreatedAt are the same

Answer (score 0):

The query below will only work if you are never updating any rows in your incremental model and all incremental runs only process new events...

```
{{ config(materialized = 'incremental') }}

 WITH people AS(
    SELECT
    {% if is_incremental() %}
        Row_Number() Over (Order by CreatedAT) + (select max(ID) from {{ this }}) AS ID, *
    {% else %}  
        Row_Number() Over (Order by CreatedAT) AS ID, *
    {% endif %}  
    FROM {{ source('leeek', 'property') }}
    {% if is_incremental() %}
     where  > (select max(CreatedAT) from {{this}})
    {% endif %}

   )
   select * from people
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this code. Its failing because the model has not been created yet: `error :people does not exist or not authorised`

Comment: Looks like there was a missing closing parenthesis in the where clause. I copy and pasted from your post which looks to have some minor syntax errors. Just double check the compiled code, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Ive modified the code from my side also, still not working, same error. The code is checking if its incremental and it is and its trying to get Max of ID but the issue is the model has not been created yet. if the initial creation has been done then, it may work

Comment: If the model hasn't been created yet, then `is_incremental()` will be false.

Comment: when it is compiled it selects the statement which says `is_incremental()` as true

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea to create a non-idempotent model. As soon as you need to run a full refresh on it, everything will not be the same.

Comment: 100% agree with @AleixCC. Recommended approach would be to build a surrogate key using the name and createdAt.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hash column to the raw data before the incremental load. Something like this could serve as a unique ID:

MD5(CONCAT(Name, CreatedAT))